# Running Selenium IDE scripts in different browser using node.js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have created multiple scripts using Selenium IDE. I can run this script only in Firefox using the extension. I want to run these scripts on different browsers like Chrome/IE using node.js. I know I can run it via java commands, but is there any way I can run it via nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Running IDE test Suites can be trigged from the command line using the selenium jar file. You can launch any browser from that command line (not just firefox).

Webdriver supports javascript/node:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html

But to run IDE tests in other browsers look at the documentation here:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Running_IDE_scripts_with_Selenium_RC

> ```
>  java 
>     -jar selenium-server.jar 
>     -userExtensions user-extensions.js
>     -htmlSuite 
>        "*chrome" 
>        "<base URL>" 
>        "<Selenium test suite file>" 
>        "<results log file>"  
>    -timeout nnnn
> ```

Specifically look at the first paramaeter after -htmlSuite:

> 1st parameter is the browser to run the script in. In RC 1.0.1 *chrome
>   = Firefox, *iehta = Internet Explorer.  (options in RC 1.0.2 are expected to be *firefox and *iexplore, respectively)